# perfect-scrollbar not work

Tags: jquery, html, css

i have a list of items inside a ul, wrapped on a div, i am using this plugin: http://www.yuiazu.net/perfect-scrollbar/

to put a "beatiful" scrollbar, but not happens, none error message appear. anyone here can help?

```
<div class="imagens">
    <div id="scroll">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="assets/img/certificado.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="assets/img/certificado-2.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="assets/img/certificado-2.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="assets/img/certificado-2.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="assets/img/certificado-2.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="assets/img/certificado-2.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="assets/img/certificado-2.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="assets/img/certificado-2.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="assets/img/certificado-2.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="assets/img/certificado-2.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="assets/img/certificado-2.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><img src="assets/img/certificado-2.jpg" alt=""></a></li>
                    </ul>
        </div>
</div><!-- /.imagens -->
```

CSS:

```
.container .certificados .colunas .coluna-cert .imagens {
    width: 401px;
    height: 471px;
    border: 5px solid #df6225;
    background: #fff;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

/* coluna selos */
.container .certificados .colunas .coluna-selos {
    float: left;
    width: 256px;
    height: 500px;
    background: #fff;
    border: 5px solid #df6225;
    border-left: 15px solid #df6225;
}

.container .certificados .colunas .coluna-selos .selo-1, .selo-2, .selo-3 {
    position: relative;
    top: 1px;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

.container .certificados .colunas .coluna-selos .selo-1 {
    margin-top: 10px;
    left: 55px;
}

.container .certificados .colunas .coluna-selos .selo-2 {
    left: 55px;
    top: 18px;
}

.container .certificados .colunas .coluna-selos .selo-3 {
    top: 30px;
    left: 55px;
}

/* lightbox certificados */
.container .certificados .colunas .coluna-cert .imagens ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    margin-top: 25px; /* cria a margem do topo da ul */
    margin-left: 35px; /* cria a margem esquerda da ul */
    padding: 0;
}

.container .certificados .colunas .coluna-cert .imagens ul li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px; /* insere um espaçamento entre as li na direita */
    margin-bottom: 10px; /* insere espaçamento no rodapé das li a partir da primeira fileira do topo */
}

.container .certificados .colunas .coluna-cert .imagens ul li:last-child {
    margin-right: 0;    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the `overflow` for your element `imagens` set to `hidden`.  This clips (hides) any content that is outside of the elements box.  You want to set `overflow:scroll` or `overflow:auto` for the parent element of the content you want to scroll.

Comment: for the plug-in to work the style of parent folder should be overflow hidden.